# handlebars template can't fill with data

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

I need to output data and fill my template throught custum function

this is my imports

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/.../handlebars/handlebars.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/.../handlebars_helpers.js') }}"></script>
```

this is my template into twig page

```
<script id="di_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {% verbatim %}
        <h1>Title </h1>
        Invoice {{ invoice.invoice_number }}
    {% endverbatim  %}
</script>
```

this my build Template Function

```
function buildTemplate(){

    context = {
        invoice: {
            invoice_number: 'val1',
            invoice_date: 'val2',
            invoice_due_date: 'val3',
            invoice_from_company: 'val4'
        }
    };

    template = $('#di_template').html();
    template_compiled = Handlebars.compile(template);
    theCompiledHtml = template_compiled(context);
    $invoice_preview.html(theCompiledHtml); 
}
```

this my result
[image]

Comment: Then don't use `verbatim`-tags as they don't parse `twig`?

Comment: Did you call the `buildTemplate` function somewhere to execute it?